# Strip double quotes from a string in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm trying to match on some inconsistently formatted HTML and need to strip out some double quotes.

Current:

```
<input type="hidden">
```

The Goal:

```
<input type=hidden>
```

This is wrong because I'm not escaping it properly:

> s = s.Replace(""","");

This is wrong because there is not blank character character (to my knowledge):

```
s = s.Replace('"', '');
```

What is syntax / escape character combination for replacing double quotes with an empty string?

Answer (score 261, accepted):

I think your first line would actually work but I think you need four quotation marks for a string containing a single one (in VB at least):

```
s = s.Replace("""", "")
```

for C# you'd have to escape the quotation mark using a backslash:

```
s = s.Replace("\"", "");
```

Comment: this has a side effect if there are more embedded quotes within the string

Answer (score 58):

I didn't see my thoughts repeated already, so I will suggest that you look at `string.Trim` in the Microsoft documentation for C# you can add a character to be trimmed instead of simply trimming empty spaces:

```
string withQuotes = "\"hellow\"";
string withOutQotes = withQuotes.Trim('"');
```

should result in withOutQuotes being `"hello"` instead of `""hello""`

Comment: 6 years later, and this is still an absolutely brilliant answer.  Thank you for this!

Answer (score 30):

```
s = s.Replace("\"", "");
```

You need to use the \ to escape the double quote character in a string.

Comment: this has a side effect if there are more embedded quotes within the string

Answer (score 17):

You can use either of these:

```
s = s.Replace(@"""","");
s = s.Replace("\"","");
```

...but I do get curious as to why you would want to do that? I thought it was good practice to keep attribute values quoted?

Comment: I'm using the HTML Agility Pack to find a certain link, and then I need to remove a value in that link from the HTML text. The HTML Agility Pack quotes the attribute values, but the original HTML is not quoted. (And all this for one test.)

Comment: this has a side effect if there are more embedded quotes within the string

Answer (score 9):

```
s = s.Replace("\"",string.Empty);
```

Comment: this has a side effect if there are more embedded quotes within the string

Answer (score 7):

If you only want to strip the quotes from the ends of the string (not the middle), and there is a chance that there can be spaces at either end of the string (i.e. parsing a CSV format file where there is a space after the commas), then you need to call the Trim function *twice*...for example:

```
string myStr = " \"sometext\"";     //(notice the leading space)
myStr = myStr.Trim('"');            //(would leave the first quote: "sometext)
myStr = myStr.Trim().Trim('"');     //(would get what you want: sometext)
```

Answer (score 6):

c#: `"\""`, thus `s.Replace("\"", "")`

vb/vbs/vb.net: `""` thus `s.Replace("""", "")`

Comment: this has a side effect if there are more embedded quotes within the string

Answer (score 4):

You have to escape the double quote with a backslash.

```
s = s.Replace("\"","");
```

Comment: this has a side effect if there are more embedded quotes within the string

Answer (score 3):

s = s.Replace(@"""", "");

Comment: this has a side effect if there are more embedded quotes within the string

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
//Sentence has quotes
string nameSentence = "Take my name \"Wesley\" out of quotes";
//Get the index before the quotes`enter code here`
int begin = nameSentence.LastIndexOf("name") + "name".Length;
//Get the index after the quotes
int end = nameSentence.LastIndexOf("out");
//Get the part of the string with its quotes
string name = nameSentence.Substring(begin, end - begin);
//Remove its quotes
string newName = name.Replace("\"", "");
//Replace new name (without quotes) within original sentence
string updatedNameSentence = nameSentence.Replace(name, newName);

//Returns "Take my name Wesley out of quotes"
return updatedNameSentence;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = s.Replace( """", "" )
```

Two quotes next to each other will function as the intended " character when inside a string.

Comment: this has a side effect if there are more embedded quotes within the string

Answer (score 1):

if you would like to remove a single character i guess it's easier to simply read the arrays and skip that char and return the array. I use it when custom parsing vcard's json. 
as it's bad json with "quoted" text identifiers.

Add the below method to a class containing your extension methods.

```
  public static string Remove(this string text, char character)
  {
      var sb = new StringBuilder();
      foreach (char c in text)
      {
         if (c != character)
             sb.Append(c);
      }
      return sb.ToString();
  }
```

you can then use this extension method:

```
var text= myString.Remove('"');
```