# Elimination of double quotes added in string of buffer while sending string of data

Tags: c#, embedded, at-command

I'm storing a string of data in an array:

```
BUFTYPE txBufmes1[] = "AT+CSCS=\"GSM\";\r\n";
BUFTYPE txBufmes2[] = "AT+CSMP=17,167,0,0\r\n";
BUFTYPE txBufmes3[]="AT+CMGF=1\r\n";
BUFTYPE txBufmes4[] = "AT+CMGS=\"81*******\"\r\n";
BUFTYPE txBufmes5[20] ="xyz";
BUFTYPE txBufsent[] = {0x1A};

UART_write(hUART, txBufmes1, sizeof(txBufmes1));
delay_ms(100);

UART_read(hUART, &rxBuf, sizeof(rxBuf));
UART_write(hUART, txBufmes2, sizeof(txBufmes2));
delay_ms(100);

UART_write(hUART, txBufmes3, sizeof(txBufmes3));
delay_ms(100);

UART_write(hUART, txBufmes4, sizeof(txBufmes4));
delay_ms(100);

UART_write(hUART, txBufmes5, sizeof(txBufmes5));
delay_ms(100);

UART_write(hUART, txBufsent, sizeof(txBufsent));
delay_ms(100);
```

When I send this data using SIM808 in phone I'm receiving a message like the one below

```
@@xyz@@
```

How to eliminate this special character `@@` when I only want to read `xyz`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip double quotes from a string in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177872/strip-double-quotes-from-a-string-in-net)

Comment: smell like all your `sizeof` must be `strlen` instead... For `txBufsent` `sizeof` seems correct